# ¿Cómo puede ser este código java en php?

Tags: php, java, http

Mi objetivo es obtener todo el código html de una página en un texto plano. Pues con el código Java que muestro si sale, pero quiero obtener el mismo resultado con php y no puedo. ¿Me podrían ayudar como hacer algo similar en php?

Éste es el código en Java:

```
StringBuilder contenido = new StringBuilder();

    //1. Definir la URL de conexion
    URL url=new URL("https://www.google.com");

    //2. Estableces una conexion HTTP simple
    HttpURLConnection conexion=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //3. Obtener un flujo de entrada de esa conexion
    try(InputStream flujoEntrada=conexion.getInputStream();
        //luego de tener en bytes InputStream, tener que leer con el BufferdReader
        BufferedReader lectorFlujo=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(flujoEntrada));){
        //4. Implementar el algoritmo de lectura lineal
        String linea= "";
        while((linea = lectorFlujo.readLine())!=null){
            contenido.append(linea).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }


    System.out.println(contenido.toString());
```

`
Intenté de esta forma en PHP, pero no me sale el mismo resultado que en java.

```
function callWebService(){ 
    return file_get_contents('https://www.google.com');
} 
$result = callWebService(); 
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

También probé con este otro código, pero no sale el mismo resultado que en java.

```
$file = file('ww');
foreach ($file as $num => $line) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($line);
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías comentar lo que pretendes? No le veo mucho sentido a abrir la página de Google para luego leerla línea por línea y mostrarla en PHP... ni tampoco en Java. ¿¡...!? Otra cosa sería un archivo de texto, un CSV, etc.

Comment: Exacto, eso mismo quiero hacer, leer linia por linia el código fuente de la ruta.

Comment: @E.Huaylla [`echo file_get_contents($url);`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) .. 1 sola línea

Comment: echo file_get_contents($url) => Ya lo probé con eso, pero no es igual, trae resultados diferentes.

Comment: ¿Pero qué salida quieres, el contenido visible de la página, el código de la página?

Comment: Muchas gracias, Como no podía solucionar tenia que buscar ayuda y es mi primera publicacion.

Comment: Vaya que ha sido difícil hacer que digas *que quieres obtener el código HTML de una página en un texto plano*. Eso era lo 1º que tenías que haber dicho. Puedes hacerlo así: **`$url='http://www.google.com';
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset= utf-8' );
echo file_get_contents($url);`** o también así: **`$url='http://www.google.com';
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset= utf-8' ); if ($stream = fopen($url, 'r')) {
    echo stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);
}`**. Fíjate que hasta es una pregunta interesante, pero mal planteada al principio. Voto para reapertura.

Comment: @E.Huaylla ¿y cuál es la diferencia con Java en lo que estás obteniendo? ¿Qué parte del string de respuesta es diferente? ¿Qué parte de la página de Google que estás obteniendo debería ser o mostrarse diferente?

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, pero igual no me sale lo mismo.

La diferencia en obtener es esta.

Comment: Pensé que se podia agregar archivos, jajajaja
La diferencia es está que esta en la ruta. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uqec2RZdshMijjbGzMFRl2M2B2RsJu1A?usp=sharing) , En google no se nota la diferencia, pero con la ruta de un video en facebook si se vé. https://www.facebook.com/ANIMETXs/videos/1818873111457067/

probar con esta ruta por favor.
A una cosa mas, el profesor en java nos enseño con servicio rest. donde  envés de traer en formato json o xml, lo traiga en texto plano de dicha ruta.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bueno, quisas algun día alguien tenga el mismo proble que yo. Luego de varios días de investigación encontré la solución.
Se puede solucionar con la libreria cURL. 
Saludos.

Comment: @E.Huaylla me alegro de que hayas encontrado la respuesta. Por favor, no la pongas en un comentario sino escribiendo una respuesta abajo. De ese modo si algún usuario tiene el mismo problema, podrá encontrar la solución de manera rápida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en tu código PHP pones antes de la salida de texto:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Entonces te sacará la salida en texto plano en lugar de en HTML. También puedes poner delante y detrás los tags pre de HTML:

```
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($result) . "</pre>";
```

De esta forma sigue siendo HTML pero ves el resultado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.